# Convert ImageMagick Command To PHP equivalent

Tags: php, ssh, imagemagick

I wish to use the following ImageMagick SSH command in PHP:

```
convert image_name.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB image_name.jpg
```

So the php ImageMagick version using:

```
$image = new Imagick('test.jpg');
$image->Functionhere()
```

Comment: What is "PHP equivalent"? php with exec( ) or Imagick ( the php/Imagemagick API ).

Comment: Is there any **code** attempts you're able to share?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it with wrapping the bash command with backticks, you also can use php's exec

```
`convert image_name.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB image_name.jpg`
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first thing is to check if you have access to imagick:

```
$version = Imagick::getVersion(); 
echo 'API version number: '.$version['versionNumber'].'<br />'; 
echo 'API version string: '.$version['versionString'].'<br />';
```

I do not like Imagick as there is not the support for it. It does not support all the options of Imagemagick. It is a class and I have never had the need to learn how to use a class and so it is more complicated than exec( ).

One thing a lot of people say is Imagick is more secure than Imagemagick; but as long as you take precautions with user data I would have thought exec( ) was nearly as secure.

```
exec( "convert image_name.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB image_name.jpg" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was:

```
$im = new Imagick( $old_file );
$im->setImageCompression( Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG );
$im->stripImage();
$im->setSamplingFactors(array('2x2', '1x1', '1x1'));
$im->setCompressionQuality('85');
```

Comment: That may be the "correct" answer but I asked you if you wanted to use Imagick or Imagemagick.